# conditional row and column selection in pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this: (c_in_node)

```
0    
1791  0.1
1792  0.3
1793  0.2
1794  0.1
...
3611  0.1
```

And an array like this: (q_flowline)

```
[0.1 0.2  -0.1 ... -0.3]
```

and two more arrays like this:

```
[1907 2343 2344 ... 3604 1845 2179] (fl_from_node)
[2343 2344 2050 ... 1918 3600 3611] (fl_to_node)
```

I want to calculate my mass in my flow but it needs to select the from_node when the q_flowline is positive and it needs to select the to_node when q_flowline is negative.

I tried:

```
m_in_flow = pd.DataFrame(c_in_node[fl_from_node if q_flowline >= 0 else fl_to_node]*q_flowline)
```

But this doesn't work. I need a DataFrame with the selection:

```
0
0.01
0.03
....
0.01
```

All these numbers should be positive.

Comment: Where does `c_in_node` come into your logic? What are its columns?

Comment: c_in_node, is the concentration at a cartain node. It's the fist dataframe I show

Comment: Sorry, `concentration at a cartain node` means nothing to me. Can you describe your *logic* in simpler terms?

Comment: I need the mass in the flowline, the flowline connects to two nodes, a from_node and a to_node. If the flow (q_flowline) is positive i need the concentration in the from_node but if the flow is negative I need the concentration in the to_node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can decipher, you need `numpy.where` to construct a vectorised if / else and feed this as a indexer to `c_in_node.loc`:

```
idx = np.where(q_flowline >= 0, fl_from_node, fl_to_node)

m_in_flow = pd.DataFrame(c_in_node.loc[idx] * q_flowline)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your dataframe `c_in_node` is a different object from your arrays. This code:

```
m_in_flow = pd.DataFrame(c_in_node[fl_from_node if q_flowline >= 0 else fl_to_node]*q_flowline)
```

is not going to give you what you want because the conditional statements do not refer to anything in the dataframe -- using the `[]` means you want to subset the dataframe using information that could be found within that dataframe itself. Otherwise, it won't know how to index the rows. Though, I will say this is what I'm assuming from your question. Seeing the actual error would help more than just saying "this doesn't work".

If your arrays are meant to be aligned together (so they have the same length), you could do something like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
q_flowline = np.array(0.1, 0.2, -0.1, -0.3)
fl_from_node = (1907, 2343, 1845, 2179)
fl_to_node = (2343, 2344, 2050, 3611)
stacked_array = np.column_stack((q_flowline, fl_from_node, flow_to_node))
stacked_df = pd.DataFrame(stacked_array, columns = ['q_flowline', 'fl_from_node', 'fl_to_node'])
full_df = pd.concat([c_in_node, stacked_df], axis=1)
pos_flowline_df = full_df['fl_from_node'][(full_df['q_flowline'] >= 0)]
neg_flowline_df = full_df['fl_to_node'][(full_df['q_flowline'] < 0)]
```

Then combine the new DFs however you need according to whatever index or sequence is required.

Note that I removed the elision from your arrays, meaning I forced them to be the same length.